# how to use BaseTokenStreamTestCase classe with maven

Tags: maven-2, lucene

I want to unit test my lucene filter (which extends TokenFilter).

I use maven.

The "BaseTokenStreamTestCase" class looks perfect but I have no idea in which maven artifactId I can find it ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class [`o.a.l.a.BaseTokenStreamTestCase.java`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/BaseTokenStreamTestCase.java) is part of Lucene's `test` tree and it doesn't seem to be published as a Maven artifact (I may be wrong but I couldn't find it in any [repository search engine](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies)). Maybe the easiest way would be to duplicate it in your own sources.

Comment: It's of course a solution. You need to duplicate LuceneTestCase and LuceneTestCaseJ4 classes too. Thanks Pascal !

Comment: @guillaume06: it's ugly but I don't have a better solution.